# What is your preferred workflow when using PhoneGap and iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, html, cordova, pycharm

What is your workflow like?  I'm trying to understand which is best.  PhoneGap only works in the simulator, so it seems rather tough to try and develop outside of that.

Here's what I've got right now:

1. Open XCode and my PhoneGap project with the www folder in it
2. Open PyCharm (my IDE) and point it at www folder
3. Edit HTML and JavaScript in PyCharm
4. Press Build/Debug in XCode and test it in the simulator

This method is SUPER slow.  I could test without the simulator, but then PhoneGap won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to test in the simulator. Most of your functionality will likely work if you browse to your www folder using Chrome or Safari. True, most PhoneGap functionality won't work (camera, geolocation, etc) but web storage works, you can test your UI, etc.